# Query MySQL PHP 6 Months in past and filter/query those results

Tags: mysql, date

I need to go back 6 Months and forward one week. Grab those records that were seen during that one week window and nothing after that one week window. I got two of the three steps completed using this:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Clients WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL`

Just one last issue to fix: I do NOT want the same client to appear in this one week window search IF they were seen AFTER that 7 day window and IF "Last_Seen" is not blank. Any idea how to accomplish this?

I fixed the following with:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Clients  WHERE  Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY  AND  Last_Seen IS NOT NULL  AND  Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY  AND  Scheduled NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND Last_Seen NOT BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 172 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND Scheduled NOT BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 365 day)`

Comment: `AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 Month)` is not comparing the date with anything. It's always true.

Comment: I think you mean `AND last_seen > DATE_SUB(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to define a ‘less than’ statement in the first attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Clients 
WHERE (CAST(Last_Seen AS DATE) = NULL 
      AND CAST(Uploaded AS DATE) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 WEEK)) 
OR 
    (CAST(Last_Seen AS DATE) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 WEEK)
    AND
    CAST(Last_Seen AS DATE) IS NOT NULL)
```

The group by is not needed unless aggregating.

This will return distinct rows with a last seen date older than 25 weeks ago, or those with no last seen value but register less than 25 weeks. If it needs to be calendar months wrap a 3 week date sub around a 5 month date sub.

Also last_seen looks like it is being referenced as a string in your example (!=‘’). If it is of string type, this will need casting to a date in all references.

Comment: Thank you Stickleback. I will give this a go in a few. I'll mark as accepted if I can get it to work. Thanks again!!

Comment: Got 2 of the three steps I need fixed. using this:   `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Clients WHERE Last_Seen BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 173 DAY AND Last_Seen IS NOT NULL ` Just one last issue to fix: I do NOT want the same client to appear AFTER that 7 day window if Last_Seen is not blank. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @Thorsverd you shouldn’t see any clients out side of that window as you’ve defined it. Though, the lower / upper boundaries will be inclusive. Anything else should not be returned. It would be really helpful to see a mock up of the original data and then the expected results covering the 3 pieces you need resolving to understand the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. I added my solution above in the question. Thank you kindly for your help!!